# How to use GetIndexedPropertyValue?

Tags: asp.net, listview, sharepoint-2010

I have the following ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv_Announcements" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="<%# Eval("Title") %>"><%# Eval("Title") %></a><br />
                <%# DataBinder.GetIndexedPropertyValue(Fields, "[\"Body\"]")%><br /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In my code behind I am doing this:

```
            lv_Announcements.DataSource = cur.Web.Lists["Announcements"].Items;
            lv_Announcements.DataBind();
```

Where `Items` is a [SPListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.aspx).  When ever I run my code I get the following error:

> The name 'Fields' does not exist in
>   the current context

Should I be doing something differently here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
<%# DataBinder.GetIndexedPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "[\"Body\"]")%>
```

DataItem is the SPListItem that the row is being bound to so you can think of it like this:

```
SPListItem myItem = //whatever;
myItem["Body"];
```

Before it would have been like this:

```
SPListItem myItem = //whatever;
myItem.Fields["Body"];
```

Which does not return the information I wanted.